# Boost_DIR-NOTFOUND on CMake

Tags: boost, cmake

I have been facing some problems when trying to configure a project with **CMake**.

Even though **CMake** seems to find the needed libs:

```
Boost version: 1.49.0
Found the following Boost libraries:
  system
  thread
  chrono
```

It still can't find its root directory:

```
Boost_DIR-NOTFOUND
```

I'm using **Linux Mint 15 (Olivia)**. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check whether the search was successful, you need to check the variable `Boost_FOUND` instead.

```
find_package(Boost [...])
if(NOT Boost_FOUND)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find boost!")
endif()
```

The `Boost_DIR` variable is only of significance when using Boost's package configuration file (which is currently no longer supported as of Boost 1.54). It is therefore perfectly fine if this value is left in the `NOTFOUND` state by the find call.

See the [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#module%3aFindBoost) for details.